# How do I make the if-statement in rails correctly to specify a flash with a key named "success"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, key

With this code I am supposed to make flashes with the key `success` different from the others by only showing the value and not the `close_flash` and `flash_background` as you can see. It doesn't work, but what do I do wrong?

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <% if key == "success" %>

    <div class="flash_<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>

  <% else %>

    <div class="flash_<%= key %>">
      <%= value %> <a href="#" class="close_flash">x</a>
    </div>
    <div class="flash_background"></div> 

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is meaningless to us. What HTML output are you getting and how does it differ from what you expect? What is the actual content of `flash`?

Comment: Did you set success as a Symbol instead of a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the flash uses symbols:

```
key == :success # true
```

In many cases, rails hashes are implemented with indifferent access.  This would mean o[:a] == o['a'] (specifically, o[:a].object_id == o['a'].object_id).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-with_indifferent_access